# data lost when read big file in chunks using fread

Tags: c++, fread

I am a novice of c++. Those are trade data of NYSE, I am using those data to do quant analysis.  A single file for one day is about 10G, so I have hundreds of those files. For the first step, I just want make sure that I could read the data by chunk correctly. Then I will maniupulate those chunk. I was told using python would be slow, so I try with c++. I try to read one file in chunks using fread(). I want to count number of lines to check my code, but it's different from the number of lines that I got when I using notepad++. Hope someone could help me with this problem thanks.

Data:

```
Q,14340,EUR/NZD,1.65027,1,1.6504,1
T,14340,EUR/NZD,1,1.65034,@,70,X
Q,14340,AUD/NZD,1.03427,1,1.03437,1
T,14340,AUD/NZD,1,1.03432,@,70,X
Q,14340,CAD/CHF,0.75142,1,0.75146,1
T,14340,CAD/CHF,1,0.75144,@,70,X
Q,14340,GBP/NZD,1.90908,1,1.90927,1
T,14340,GBP/NZD,1,1.90918,@,70,X
Q,14340,GBP/CHF,1.312,1,1.31208,1
T,14340,GBP/CHF,1,1.31204,@,70,X
Q,13724,#6S,0.9928,12,0.9929,29
```

number of lines using fread:     279 174 248

number of lines using notepad++:279 485 508

Wrong Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    clock_t start = clock();
    char buffer[100000]="\0";
    int cursor = sizeof(buffer);
    FILE* fp;
    int Judge;
    int offset = 0;
    Judge = fopen_s(&fp, "E:\\feedRec\\TFD20190227", "r");
    int count = 0;
    int num = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        //read one chunk
        num=fread(buffer, sizeof(char), (sizeof(buffer) - 1), fp);
        // null terminated the buffer
        buffer[num] = '\0';
        char* ptr=buffer;
        while (*ptr!='\0') {
            if (*ptr == '\n') {
                count++;
            }
            ptr++;
        }
        //Since the lines are not formatted. The buffer will end at
        //the middle of the line. So I need to move back the pointer 
        //back to the beginning of the sliced line to let it be read in 
        //the next loop. 
        //T,14340,AUD/NZD,1,1.03432,@,70,X
        //if buffer end here|
        //pointer need to be move back to the beginning.
        //T,14340,AUD/NZD,1,1.03432,@,70,X
        //|
        //calculte the offset
        offset = 0;
        cursor = sizeof(buffer)-1;
        while (buffer[cursor] != '\n') {
            cursor--;
            offset++;
        }
        //move back the pointer 
        if (offset > 0 && (num == sizeof(buffer) - 1)) {
            fseek(fp, -offset, SEEK_CUR);
        }
        //clear the buffer
        memset(buffer, '\0', sizeof(buffer) - 1);
        // deal with last chunk: if the num less than buffer size, stop
        if (num < sizeof(buffer)-1) 
        {
            fclose(fp); break; 
        }
    }
    //count the last chunk
    char* ptr = buffer;
    while (*ptr != '\0') {
        if (*ptr == '\n') {
            count++;
        }
        ptr++;
    }
    cout << "count: " << count << endl;
    clock_t end = clock();
    cout << "time : " << ((double)end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << "s\n";
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The code with `fscanf_s` is counting words, not lines. `"%s"` reads up to the next whitespace and your example has a space between 1 and T. You could use `fgets` to count lines and long as your buffer is larger than the longest line..

Comment: Using `fread()` to read variable-length lines of data is not the best use of the function.  Use `fgets()` or POSIX `getline()` to read lines.  If you are reading from a file, the standard I/O functions will buffer the input anyway.  If you want, you can set a larger than usual buffer size with `setvbuf()` immediately after opening the file.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I am sorry that I check with another file, the result is not same again.

Comment: You null terminate at the full buffer size rather than after the last byte read.  That will miscount any short buffer read (such as the last one).  Use `num`, not `sizeof(buffer)-1`.

Comment: What's all the seeking about? Seems like if all you want to do is count newlines you'd read a chunk, count the newlines, read the next chunk, etc.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You mean buffer[num] = '\0'; ? Still doesn't work.

Comment: If the stated goal is "count number of lines", then what's with multiple loops, running everywhere and counting newline characters, in many different ways? Does that make sense to you? What does all of that do, that a single loop, that simply counts newlines in the buffer, doesn't do? And the logic that detects end of file seems to be broken, since the loop always thinks that a full buffer is read, every time, and does some unclear logic to figure out otherwise. Have you tried [explaining every line of this program to your rubber duck](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)?

Comment: @RetiredNinja I am a novice of c. Those are trade data of NYSE, I am using those data to do quant analysis. For the first step, I just want make sure that I could read the data by chunk correctly. Then I will maniupulate those chunk. I was told using python would be slow, so I try with c.

Comment: Note that you're not using C — you are using C++ because of the headers you use and notations such as `using namespace std;` and `cout << …`.  Make sure you know which language you are working with!

Comment: Well, presumably you're going to want to parse that CSV data into a struct or something so you can work with it. I'd just read it one line at a time, split it on the commas, and do what you need to do with it. File I/O is always going to consume some time and it does make sense that reading a bigger chunk might be better but with caching and such it may not make as much difference as you'd think. I'd focus on getting a baseline that is correct and then maybe worry about trying to optimize it if you must with the baseline to measure against.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thanks for your suggestion. I add some comments to my code. Sorry about that. First question on stackoverflow.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I am faint. Sorry, last reply is I am using c++.

Comment: You can clean up your last comment if you're quick.  Or delete it and replace it without needing to admit being faint. 

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I deeply feel that I am a human being or a animal, not a machine. I thought I typed ++, but actually there were no "++".

Comment: Adding comments won't change the fact that the shown logic is fundamentally broken, for the reasons I explained in my first comment. Adding more comments is not going to fix that. Again: try to focus your attention on a simple fact that if the goal here is to count the number of lines, then having multiple loops, all looking for newlines in the read buffer, is completely illogical. Only one is needed. Additionally, multiple people pointed out to you all the multiple logical flaws in how the shown code attempts to detect the end of the file. What part of that is unclear to you, exactly?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik  "looking for newlines in the read buffer, is completely illogical". Thanks for reminding me. There are NUL char in some lines, using "*ptr!='\0'" to determined whether it reached the end of the buffer is wrong: T,14369,GBP/USD,1,1.33012,@,70,X LF
T,14370,TIME$,1,9453,@,40, NUL LF
Q,10516,#YKH9,901.125,1,911.875,2 LF. The loop terminated after "@,40 "

Comment: If it is line based data, use std::getline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are NUL char in some lines, using "*ptr!='\0'" to determined whether it reached the end of the buffer is wrong:

T,14369,GBP/USD,1,1.33012,@,70,X LF
T,14370,TIME$,1,9453,@,40, NUL LF
Q,10516,#YKH9,901.125,1,911.875,2 LF

The loop terminated after "@,40 ".

```
clock_t start = clock();
char buffer[300]="\0";
int cursor = sizeof(buffer);
FILE* fp;
int Judge;
int offset = 0;
Judge = fopen_s(&fp, "E:\\feedRec\\TFD20190228", "rb");
int count = 0;
size_t num = 0;
while (1)
{
    num=fread(buffer, sizeof(char), (sizeof(buffer) - 1), fp);

    buffer[num] = '\0';


    char* ptr=buffer;
    char* endptr = &buffer[num];
    int ct = 0;
    if (num == sizeof(buffer) - 1) 
    {     
        while (ptr != endptr) {
            ct++;
            if (*ptr == '\n') {
                count++;
            }
            ptr++;
        }
    }
    offset = 0;
    cursor = sizeof(buffer)-1;
    while (buffer[cursor-1] != '\n') {
        cursor--;
        offset++;
    }

    if (offset > 0 && (num == sizeof(buffer) - 1)) {
        fseek(fp, -offset, SEEK_CUR);
    }
    
    if (num < sizeof(buffer)-1) 
    {
        fclose(fp); break; 
    }
    memset(buffer, '\0', sizeof(buffer) - 1);
}

char* ptr = buffer;
char* endptr = &buffer[num];
int ct = 0;
if (num == sizeof(buffer) - 1)
{
    while (ptr != endptr) {
        ct++;
        if (*ptr == '\n') {
            count++;
        }
        ptr++;
    }
}
cout << "count: " << count << endl;
clock_t end = clock();
cout << "time : " << ((double)end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << "s\n";
fclose(fp);
return 0;
```